# Good profile urls using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've three url types which are as follows:

`http://www.mywebsite.com/myprofile.php?user_username=username`
`http://www.mywebsite.com/input.php?user_username=username`
`http://www.mywebsite.com/users.php?user_username=username`

Currently, users have to type the whole address like (`http://www.mywebsite.com/myprofile.php?user_username=username`) to go to their profiles and the same with input and users.

What I want is if a user types `http://www.mywebsite.com/profile/username`, he would be automatically redirected to `http://www.mywebsite.com/myprofile.php?user_username=username`.

When a user types `http://www.mywebsite.com/input/username`, he would be redirected to
`http://www.mywebsite.com/input.php?user_username=username`.

When a user types `http://www.mywebsite.com/username`, he would be redirected to `http://www.mywebsite.com/users.php?user_username=username`.

I know that this can only be achieved through `.htaccess`. However, I've searched but with no fruitful result.

Any help please!

**Update**

I think that the following code is close to being correct. However, I'm not getting the correct result and the css is also getting messed a lot. Individually they are working but together they are messing up. Any help please.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /myprofile\.php\?user_username=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /myprofile/%2\? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !user_username=
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ myprofile.php?user_username=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /user\.php\?user_username=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ //%2\? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !user_username=
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user.php?user_username=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /input\.php\?user_username=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /input/%2\? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !user_username=
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ input.php?user_username=$1 [L]
```

Comment: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/ - this might help

Comment: Please note that you want an *internal rewrite* to happen, not an *external redirect*. The first one simply rewrites an url internally to some working script, while the latter lets the client redo the request to a new url. This changes the url that is displayed in the browser too, which is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks @dream_machine for the share! It really helped a lot. Although I couldn't make it work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+input\.php\?user_username=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /input/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+myprofile\.php\?user_username=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /profile/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+user\.php\?user_username=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^input/([^/]+)/?$ input.php?user_username=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/?$ myprofile.php?user_username=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ users.php?user_username=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Add these to the `.htaccess` file in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ users.php?user_username=$1 [DPI,L]
RewriteRule ^input/([^/]+)/?$ input.php?user_username=$1 [DPI,L]
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/?$ myprofile.php?user_username=$1 [DPI,L]
```

Tested in Apache 2.2 and 2.4 :)

This assumes that mod_rewrite is **both** installed **and** activated for htaccess files. 
If you are not sure, to check if mod_rewrite is installed, look at the list of installed modules in the output of `phpinfo();`
By default, mod_rewrite is not enabled for htaccess files. If you are managing your own server, open `httpd.conf`
and make sure that the webroot directory block contains one of these lines: `AllowOverride FileInfo` or `AllowOverride All`

Comment: I pasted this code in my `.htaccess`. I guess that you're trying to tell me that my `.htaccess` should only contain this code. Right? It didn't work though!

Comment: `It didn't work` doesn't work on this site... You have to be more specific.

Comment: Actually I didn't get any result. I mean to say that it's similar to adding no codes to my `.htaccess`.

Comment: `.htaccess` is in my root folder and the contents are `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ users.php?user_username=$1 [DPI,L]
RewriteRule ^input/([^/]+)/?$ input.php?user_username=$1 [DPI,L]
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/?$ myprofile.php?user_username=$1 [DPI,L]`